# make scrollable layout and fragment that use this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity with navigation drawer. I created a fragment for each item in my nav drawer. I have a toolbar.xml that included in my content.xml and I want to set my content.xml as default layout for my fragments. but I want to make it scrollable because some of my fragments have many text & images! 
how can I do that?

this is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_24dp);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.intro) {
                IntroFragment introFragment = new IntroFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragment, introFragment).commit();
            }


            return false;

        }

    });

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.khat) {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }

        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;
}


public void onBackPressed(){
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }else {super.onBackPressed();}

}
}
```

this is my content.xml that I want to set it as my default layout for fragments.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_for_fragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#132740">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my introFragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.arsh.enc.IntroFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/introfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
            android:text="VERY VERY
VERY VERY

VERY VERY

VERY VERY

VERY VERY LONG TEXT"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how to do it.
can I do that? if yes, how?

Comment: what is going wrong right now? you have your scrollview inside the fragment where it should be

Comment: @DreamersOrg my layout is not scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use `ScrollView` in your layout.

You can use

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

in your xml file.

And then in your `MainActivity.java` get your textView5 and try this:

```
textView5.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Let me know, if that worked.